# Ruby on Rails: undefined method `current_user?`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having issues trying to figure out why i'm getting `undefined method`current_user?'`

In my Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  # Force signout to prevent CSRF attacks
  def handle_unverified_request
    sign_out
    super
  end

   private
    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
     helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not Autherized" if current_user.nil?
  end

  def track_activity(trackable, action = params[:action])
    current_user.activities.create! action: action, trackable: trackable
  end
end
```

In my session helper:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

I'm still new to rails I'm following some tutorials, but I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting undefined method for current_user?

This is where my error is occurring- users view folder:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: where did u get the undefined method error?

Comment: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-current_user_p Listing 9.16.

Comment: @DennyMueller i have the `unless current_user?(@user)...` code in my `_follow_form.html.erb` inside users folder in views folder

Comment: @Sunxperous Ohhhh I seee!!

Comment: can you see if the answer solves your problem @andrewliu ?

Answer (score 4):

You have not defined a `current_user?` method anywhere, and you are calling `current_user?(@user)`.

Perhaps, you need to call `signed_in?` instead of `current_user?`, or define what you mean by `current_user?(@user)`

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `current_user?` method.
there is a difference between `current_user` and `current_user?` `current_user?` always return a boolean response.

but you can try with `current_user(@user)?` or `unless current_user(@user).nil?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  def current_user?(user)
     user == current_user
  end
```